# QGIS - Many raster - change resolution, coordinate system and export

Tags: qgis, raster, export, qgis-processing, batch

I have ca. 50 rasters and I want to batch export them after changing the resolution and coordinate system. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you asking how to access the batch mode on the GDAL tool `warp-reproject`? Via the button at the bottom left.

Comment: Thank you, its so simple ;)